# Desktop will not completely shutdown unless I unplug it

Tags: boot, bios, shutdown

I have Dell Inspiron 570 PC that I was working on, doing tests like Memtest and other things that are on Hirens Boot CD 15.2 (HBCD) to insure the hardware was working OK before I loaded the OS on the unit.

Whenever I attempted to power down the unit using the power button, which it did power down after the 4 second hold, it would boot back up after it shut down. Also before I loaded the OS, an error would appear temporarily while I had the HBCD in the drive then after 30 seconds or so it would boot to CD. The error message was something like, blah blah PCX blah blah configuration not set right. The BIOS was very hard to get into, but managed to get in and reset defaults and a few other thing to try to get the shut down to go properly. Hard to get into, as in pressing F2 at startup did not do anything, only after a number of tries and I know the keyboard works, it is the one I use on the PCs I have on the bench.

I did not write down the error, that is why it is written as crappily as it is. I did set the PC so it will not boot using the onboard LAN.

So I thought maybe the PC is looking for an OS to boot to since the PC is UEFI, and it was looking for a boot sector.... So I  loaded the OS and still no joy.

Last thing i tried was to update the BIOS after the OS was installed Old version was 01 and the new version is 06. Updated through windows successfully, but still reboots at all times, shutting it down in any way, unless I pull the plug. It will not boot back up when I plug it back in unless I hit the power button.

Answer (score 0):

Check the BIOS settings for Wake on {any device}.

Then shut down from the Start Button (Shut Down) instead of the power button.

This will work if the OS installed properly.

If not, then run Hardware tests on the computer to see if there is a hardware error.

Comment: I did  disable the wake on setting, and I also tried the shut down numerous times by the shut down at the start button, besides the power button. It may be a bad MOBO but I wanted to get this out there to see if there were any other tricks I am thinking it is a hardware problem not software since it did this before the OS was installed

Comment: I edited my answer to provide for motherboard tests. Good boards and good installs will always shut down properly

Comment: I did mention I ran hardware tests before the install of the OS, and the PC was rebooting then, that's why the tests. Dell has an "onboard preboot assesment" diagnostic in the BIOS that I ran before and running it again now as we speak.

Comment: So my initial answer was (in part) for BIOS settings. Did you find that helpful?

Comment: I did not use the right term when I mentioned in my question that "I did set the PC so it will not boot using the onboard LAN." But I will go over the BIOS one more time to see if I missed anything. I do find tis curious though, I have worked on 100s of computers over the past 20 years as a hobby, and never had an issue like this. The PC works perfectly otherwise.

Comment: Everything was disabled when I checked it

Comment: There would appear to be a hardware issue then.